# Folly on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-c++, folly

Has anybody actually succeeded working with Folly (e.g. fbvector and such) classes on MSVC?

I am unable to find any sensible information, for example, it fails to compile for not finding folly-config.h while the only thing I find online is a github revision that it "was removed because it is automatically created by Configure" and information on what is this configure and how to launch it is nowhere to be found.

Comment: On Linux, the `configure` file is created by running autoconf on the `configure.ac` file. I don't think you can do the same on Windows (or maybe using cygwin ?).

Comment: You could also try MSYS. This works fine with MinGW-gcc, but if you set the `CC` environment variable accordingly, I see no reason why it shouldn't work with MSVC.

Comment: I don't know why this question was closed as non-constructive. The answer is on a comment by Tudor Bosman on Sutter's Mill. Folly is targetted at CentOS linux x86_64. Portability was not facebook's goal in open sourcing it.
http://herbsutter.com/2012/06/02/facebook-folly-oss-c-libraries/

Comment: For anyone who finds this in 2017: it sort-of works now (sometimes, mostly): https://github.com/facebook/folly/issues/529